# Why does the Discord strategy for Passport not redirect me to log in?

Tags: discord, passport.js

I am trying to use the discord passport strategy to allow users to log into my website so that I can display some of the servers that they are in. I have the first code block in my app.js file and the second code block in one of my routers.

```
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
passport.use(new DiscordStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.clientID,
    clientSecret: process.env.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: process.env.callbackURL,
    scope: ["identify", "guilds", "guilds.join"]
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    User.findOrCreate({ discordId: profile.id }, function(err, user) {
        return cb(err, user);
    })
}))
```

When I try to hit the router, I am taken to the OAuth screen and then redirected to my callback link (which is /callback) but I am getting a ReferenceError: User is not defined. What is causing this error?

```
router.route("/callback").get(passport.authenticate('discord', {
    failureRedirect: '/'
}), function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/dashboard') // Successful auth
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add serialization and deserialization for your user object.

```js
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
passport.use(new DiscordStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.clientID,
    clientSecret: process.env.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: process.env.callbackURL,
    scope: ["identify", "guilds", "guilds.join"]
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    // btw it seems that User here is not defined, make sure it exists
    // maybe you forgot a require?
    User.findOrCreate({ discordId: profile.id }, function(err, user) {
        return cb(err, user);
    })
}))

// Serialize and Deserialize

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id)
})

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  const user = // get user object from your database here using the id parameter
  if (user) done(null, user)
})
```